# SSRS 2008 Having a problem when adding Page Name

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When modify the properties of a tablix and add anything to the 'PageName' property, it changes my 
report definitions from

```
 <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

to

```
 <Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the PageName property is only supported in SSRS 2008 R2 and above so the report designer is updating the definition to that version.